# WPF/XAML (Window.Resources) cannot find ClassName in NameSpace

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid, resources

I have a problem that I have spent a lot of time to resolve in vain.

I have created a class name in spacename "ComboBoxDGWPF":

```
public class StatusList : List<string>
{
    public StatusList()
    {
        this.Add("Assigned");
        this.Add("Closed");
        this.Add("In Progress");
        this.Add("Open");
        this.Add("Resolved");
    }
}
```

In XAML, I create a `staticData` like that:

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxDGWPF.Window1"
    ....
    xmlns:staticData="clr-namespace:ComboBoxDGWPF"
    ....
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <staticData:StatusList x:Key="StatusList"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    ....
</Window>       <!-- Added by edit -->
```

But in XAML it gives me an error:

> the name 'StatusList' does not exist in NameSpace 'clr-namespace:ComboBoxDGWPF'.

I'm 100% sure that there is the 'public class StatusList' in that namespace.

I don't understand why this error occurs?
See attached code source for details.

Comment: can you successfully build your solution?

Comment: @HuaVanDong: Are you getting an error when you try to build and run your application or is it a designer issue only?